# What is the best way to run a C DLL in client side?

Tags: c, web, dll, client-side, blazor

I'm looking for a language and framework to do a job, which needs to run a C DLL in the client side. I found Blazor, I think its possible to do with it. I couldn't find any good way to make this DLL call from javascript.

Should I try it with Blazor? Anyone know a better way?

Comment: Opinion: Blazor is horrible. Fact: You cannot run a DLL with client side JavaScript. However if you are using Node, take a look at this https://benfarrell.com/2013/01/03/c-and-node-js-an-unholy-combination-but-oh-so-right/

Comment: I'm choosing a language to do the job. I need to run the DLL in the client side, so if it's impossible to run a DLL in JavaScript i will need to use another way.
I saw about Note.js, it runs in the server-side, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. I don't think it's possible to run a DLL in a browser using nothing but client side javascript. There has to be some server component involved at some point.

Comment: Maybe I found a way to do that. I think I can use WebAssembly.

Comment: That is one thing Blazor offers. I think it may still be in beta though. Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... which needs to run a C DLL in the client side

That won't happen.

> I found Blazor, I think its possible to do with it.

No. BlazorWasm will run .net DLLs but not C DLLs.
Your only chance in this direction would be to find the source for that DLL and recompile the C code to Wasm.

But the more realistic option is to run the DLL on the server and expose it through an API.

Comment: I have the C code. I will compile the C code into a Wasm and call it in Javascript. Thanks for all!